# How do i implement a route that is strictly for an external redirect in Angular2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

What is the correct way to create a route that is strictly for external redirect, but also adds some url parameters to it?

In my example, I want to create a "/Register" route that first appends some parameters programatically, then redirects to a registation/login website.

Here's the flow:

1) User clicked on link in email and hits angular site: "http://my.site.com/Register?token=1234"

2)  Angular site does some work and redirects to "http://login.site.com/Register?token=1234&extrainfo=4567"

**I know how to solve this, but it seems like a hack.  That's because i'm using a component that i don't actually need. Would prefer to use a "service" of some sorts...**

I'm creating a component, that implements CanActivate.

```js
{ path: 'Register', component: RegisterRedirectComponent, canActivate: [RegisterRedirectComponent] },

 // actually a component, because we need to provide a component to routes
```

I implement canactivate, which is always going to return false, because it's going to do a redirect beforehand.

```js
import * as ng from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

/*
This is a component trick so that we can implement a redirector using canactivate.
The routing path leads to this component, which is never reached, because canactivate is always false and forces a redirect.
Replace with better solution in future... this is a useless "Component".
*/

@ng.Component({
template: ''    
})
export class RegisterRedirectComponent implements CanActivate {
    constructor() {}

    canActivate() {
        // Get current url
        // Do some work to get extra parameters
        // Append to url
        window.location.href = // url
        return false;
    }
}
```